# How to find which solution has a ribbon button in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have inherited a heavily customised - hardly documented CRM 2011 instance. There are over 80 in-house managed solutions and one of them contains a ribbon button that isn't working as desired.

What is the quickest way to find which solution contains the button?

I'm figuring that I'm going to have to export the most likely candidates unzip them and search through the files in what is looking like the most epic needle and haystack adventure of my life. I would like to avoid this brute force approach if I can.

Comment: Are they managed or unmanaged solutions? Also what entity or other location is the button on?

Comment: managed solutions...Case Entity in the Homepage Ribbontype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a lot of solution, can you add one more :) in that solution you can only include your *Application Ribbon* component and *Case* entity. Fix appropriate button and import solution after 80 others.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: But if that is not an option, you can find that in database. Get record in table *[RibbonDiffBase]* where *[RDX]* column contains ID of your ribbon button. Then, when you have results, check *SolutionId* column. You have all solution IDs which have included definition for your ribbon button.

Next, go through *[SolutionBase]* table and find Name of your solution (based on SolutionID).

I still preffer my first answer, it is more elegant. But, also hope that second part of answer will be helpful.

Comment: But I need to find the original button and code so I can work out what is wrong with it.

Comment: thanks for the extra info. I needed to know which of the 80 have this customisation so I could compare what is deployed with what is in source control. (it looks like previous devs never raised the version number) I'll try your query and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks to your extra advice...I have been able to document where a lot of features are. We are trying to consolidate them all into as few solutions as feasibly possible. It's mundane work but it is already saving us some pain.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ribbon Workbench:
http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx 
You will get an error logg directly when you load each solution, hopefully sith the exact faulty ribbon button also, this is not the case always, mot often!

Good luck